# Isometric invariants

Tags: differential-geometry

Arbitrarily combining Christopher symbols and partial derivatives of the first fundamental form coefficients (classical surface theory) a lot of isometric functions/dependents can be defined/synthesized/manufactured.

Can each of them be described as some unidentified property in isometry? Do they all remain invariant under isometric deformations/mappings? I mean just in principle, even if they are all not terribly interesting for the time being?